# Delay after a MAC change

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet, mac-address

I am writing a script that will change my ethernet MAC address on a local network. It will work as follows:

1. Initially eth0 will be brought down
2. MAC will be changed using the ifconfig utility
3. eth0 will be brought up

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 5
ifconfig eth0 down
sleep 10
ifconfig eth0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
sleep 1
ifconfig eth0 up
```

If I execute the above script, the MAC changes successfully, also the network icon in the panel shows 'Connecting' status, and **after few seconds** the eth0 gets connected to the network again.
Then I added few lines to increase the functionality of my code-

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0| grep 'inet addr:'
ifconfig eth0 | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $5}'
ping 192.168.1.107 -c 2
```

The above lines displays the new IP address, MAC address and also sends a ping request to confirm that network is working as usual.
But the problem I'm facing is that after adding the above lines, I get a ping failure, and also the network icon in the panel shows 'Connecting' status. After the script is completely executed, **after few seconds**, the eth0 is connected completely. (ping can be done)
So I tried adding sleep 30 after the following line

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

assuming it would fix the ping issue. But still the ping(mentioned in the script) fails and the network takes some time after the execution of the script to establish a complete connection.
How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Which distribution are you using?  Basically, MAC address change should get done before starting NetworkManager.  Possible options are:

- Install a custom udev rule for eth0.
- Write a script working with your init system (sysvinit, upstart, systemd, etc).
- Utilize [systemd.link](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html) feature of systemd.

I found [useful info at archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing).  You might also be interested in [macchanger](https://github.com/alobbs/macchanger), which is commonly available in various distributions.